# applying armature scale yield to change object location

Tags: armature, scale

What I want to do is apply the scale of the armature, when applying the position of the armature changes.

Here's the armature before applying the scale:

[image]

After applying the armature scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> Apply scale) the location of the armature is changed.

[image]

As you can see, I have no animations and no delta transform, so why does this happen and how to solve it?.

If I enter the edit mode, the armature is back to position, but when I back to object mode it is shifted as you can see:

[image]

Here's the blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hmef1zb-QDFNkFxServ52shOLsP2Vt4y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

As you can see your armature has a pose, it has been moved away from its origin and keyframed in *Pose* mode. If you apply the scale in *Object* mode, the bones will keep this distance from the origin but, as the armature has been scaled down, the distance will be scaled up as much. So what you need to do before applying the scale is go in *Pose* mode and reset the pose with an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: That works! thank you! I have keyframe animation in another file with about 178 frames, how to reset the pose for all the keyframes without effecting the animation in order to apply the scale after?

Comment: can you please help with this, if there is an animation, how can it be done?

Comment: hello, yes good question, I never had to do it, I'm looking for a solution

Comment: Ok so I created this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/applying-armature-scale-messes-up-the-action/197023#197023 and this time it's fixed  ;p   you need to apply the scale, go in the Graph Editor, type Location in the filter, make sure that the Pivot Point is on 2D Cursor, put the cursor at frame 0, scale all the curves on the Y axis down to 0.018...