# Applying armature scale messes up the action

Tags: armature

It's a question derived from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196162/applying-armature-scale-yield-to-change-object-location/196194?noredirect=1#comment330359_196194) initial question. Scaling the armature messes up the action because it changes the bone locations. How can I apply the scale of the armature, but keep the original action?

Before applying:

[image]

After applying:

[image]

[Here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/yNDqbr5d/) is the original armature with an action.

**Edit** : So I was finally able to fix the problem with WiSHFul97's method, applying the scale, going into the *Graph Editor*, typing *Location* in the filter, I just needed the *Pivot Point* to be set on *2D Cursor*, then scale on the Y axis down to the armature original scale!! thanks WiSHFul97!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since F-Curve points for each bone are calculated w.r.t. the rest position of the bone, we can kinda get away with scaling them w.r.t. y=0 axis.

see this for clarification:

[image]

In this gif, I created 3 dummy bones and animated them. Then I scaled them in object mode and applied the scale. Then in the pose mode I selected all the bones and in graph editor, I selected all the location curves and scaled them on the y-axis by 2. You can see the root bone is now traveling 4 units and the scale is 1 in object mode.

Comment: thanks, I was finally able to fix with this method, each time I forgot something, like setting the Pivot Point to 2D Cursor in the Graph Editor