# Model Scaling Breaking Animation

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

I've imported a model with pre-made animations and a rig. Scaling down the model (via the rig) works and the animations are okay, but trying to animate the rig's motion causes the rig to default back to its initial scale.

I parented it to an empty which works. However, trying to edit an animation also causes this issue, and I'm worried about the issue being triggered by other things.

Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? How can I apply the new scale without breaking the animations?

Comment: I've asked a quite similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/applying-armature-scale-messes-up-the-action ... not sure your problem is the same though, so maybe share your file (just the animated armature): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots It's not exactly a fix, as it removes all 'location' data from the animation; anything dependent on location is lost. Scaling down the 'location' did make the animation 'work', but I need location data preserved.

Comment: hard to tell without the file, maybe your armature scale has been keyframed at the beginning of the action?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, just found out you can just parent it to an empty and scale the empty. Simple solution, but appears to work!