# Why is my limb flipping when trying at constain to armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

edit:
I don't know what exactly I did but I fixed it... I renamed my bones as for some reason all my bones had "L" on the end of them, I must have forgot to change the names after mirroring, maybe this will work for you if you have this problem too.

I'm trying to figure out why my character's upper leg rotates by 180 when constraining to my armature's bone. even if the weight is as small as 0.0001 the same thing happens. I've tried applying transforms and clearing but nothing seems to work, I'm really stumped. Sorry if this isn't enough information I'm not sure what else to write. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117832/discussion-on-question-by-dani-arkadia-why-is-my-limb-flipping-when-trying-at-co).

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up :

- Join all the meshes within one object
- Recalculate the normals in *Edit* mode
- Apply the scale of both the armature and the mesh (once done read [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/applying-armature-scale-messes-up-the-action) to correct the armature)
- Select the knees of the armature and in *Edit* mode bend them a bit forward
- Enable the *Deform* option for each bone that is supposed to act on the mesh (not the IK targets or pole target, not the root bone)
- Select the object, shift select the armature, parent *With Empty Groups*, then switch the object to *Edit* mode, select one mesh after the other, and in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups* list, select the group it is supposed to be part of and click *Assign*
- Correct the *IK* constraint *Pole Angle* value if necessary