# Scaling Skeleton on axis breaks animation

Tags: animation, armature, transforms

I have a model and animation that I want to flip on the Z axis, it looks just fine before I apply the scale however once the scale is applied it breaks the animation.

Before Applying Scale:

[image: Animation Working]

After Applying Scale:

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe this will answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/applying-armature-scale-messes-up-the-action

Comment: Unfortunately this fix didn't seem to work, I think it's due to the fact I'm only scaling on a single axis, mirroring the model basically.

Even if it did work, I've also got multiple animation so I'd need to go through them all doing it manually.