# Applying scale on armature changes parented objects location

Tags: armature, bones

I have an armature with parented objects related to it and I want to resize it and apply its scale so it would be at the default 1.000 instead of around  1.8 which it is currently. But , when I apply the scale the parented objects relative location to their respective bones change. Is there a way to avoid it?

[image: Before applying scale]

[image: After applying scale]

Comment: maybe my question here will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/applying-armature-scale-messes-up-the-action