# Help scaling an armature and mesh (FBX import)

Tags: armature

I'm using Blender 3.3.1.  I imported a free elephant that is rigged of sketchfab (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/hide-the-elephant-g-baselitz-version-49bd291888204d45adf6074f764735a1) which is pretty cool and I'm using it to learn some things.

I'm having problems with the armature set to 0.010 scale and the mesh was at 1.0 scale.   For my application,  need both to be at 1.0 scale.  I did some research and see this is common, and found a solution suggested that works so far which is to import the FBX at 100 scale. That worked great and both mesh and its parented armature are at 1.0.

[image]

My problem is now I need to bring the size of the elephant down to normal scale again, and when I try and scale down the mesh deforms.  Here for example I tried to scale it down to 0.20 ... so far so good.

[image]

But as soon as I select-all and apply all transforms, the mesh deforms and gets worse and worse the more I scale down, which is basically unrecoverable at .01 where I need it to be.

[image]

What can I do to make this the proper scale without deforming, and have the armature scale at 1.0 and the mesh at 1.0?  I also attached the blend file.  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello for some reason I can't open your blend file, could you please save and share again?

Comment: @moonboots the file is actually a zip file with the wrong file extension ("Elephant.zip.blend"). You need to rename it and remove the "*.blend*" part, then you can extract the zip file to get the real blend file.

Comment: Thanks Blunder. I'm not sure what's the problem though, maybe it's the same as this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/applying-armature-scale-messes-up-the-action

Comment: Thanks, here's a better link the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFeQc8G-7nqJ3vhNOuWMQ1NtTQ1rRfEK/view?usp=sharing  I'll take a look at those posts above, I've seen them before but could not work it out.  Will try again.